# Bash Script, скопировать содержимое файла storyboard в другой storyboard

Tags: xcode, objective-c, bash, macos, shell

Есть файл, назовем его
abc.storyboard с содержимым .xml

в этой же папке есть файл с одинаковым расширением example.storyboard

Как скопировать данные из abc.storyboard в файл example.storyboard
Чтобы в итоге они имели одинаковое содержимое.

Comment: Вообще не понятно, чем вам помочь.

Comment: @Pro100Denysko подправил описание

Comment: `$ cp abc.storyboard example.storyboard`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin как-то похоже долго сидел за этим вопросом и немножко протупил, так как использовал команду постоянно с параметрами -f -R. Спасибо большое за помощь.